# Jenkins - Stage before "Source Code Management"

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I need my build to run only if some conditions are met.
For that I need to insert a check procedure before running the built-in "Source Code Management" that updates the svn working copy.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin):

- <your project> → *configure*
- Disable the builtin SCM: → *Source Code Management* → *None*
- → *Add build step* → *Conditional step (multiple)*
- Configure the *Run?* condition according to your needs
- → *Add step to condition* → *Execute shell* → *Commands:* ... the commands to update your SVN working copy ...
- → *Add step to condition* → ... whatever your build is supposed to do ...

2) Or create an extra project containing your *check procedure* and trigger your project as its downstream project according to its build result.

Comment: If I will not use "Source Code Management" then it will not write the changelog.xml which I use to get the comments on the commits (I need that because I force the users to write jira issue keys on their commits comments so i can update the issues during the build).